# How to download Outlook attachments after receiving new mail from specified receiver in python

Tags: python, vba, outlook, office-automation

I created a python script for downloading outlook attachments from a specified sender. I want to download outlook attachment automatically once a new mail is received from a specified sender. For example my sender send at 10.30 Am & attachment should be download on time.(10.30/10.31). Can this be done using VBA?

Below is my mail attachment's downloading script.

```
from pathlib import Path
from pyexpat.errors import messages
import win32com.client
import os,sys
import time
import glob
import subprocess
import xlwings as xw
import shutil 

#Check existing & create folder
output_dir=Path.cwd() / "Output"
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

print("Success")
inbox.Name

messages=inbox.items
ytemails=[message for message in inbox.Items if 
message.SenderEmailAddress.endswith('123@gmail.com')]
i1=0

for message in ytemails:
  print("insta =",message)
  i1=i1+1
  sender=message.Sender
  subject = message.Subject
  body=message.body
  attachments=message.Attachments
  print(str(i1))
    if(str(sender).__contains__("inqube")):
    print("message =",message)
    #time.sleep(20)

    target_folder=output_dir / str(subject)

    if os.path.exists(target_folder):
        print(str(target_folder))
        print("Error")

    elif (target_folder.exists):
        print(str(target_folder))
        target_folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    print("step >> "+str(i1))
    for attachment in attachments:
        print(str(attachment))
        attachment.SaveAsFile(target_folder / str(attachment))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class if you need to handle incoming emails instantly. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID represented by the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Also you may hook the `ItemAdd` event of the `Items` class for the Inbox folder. Both approaches have its pros and cons.

But never iterate over all items in the folder:

```
ytemails=[message for message in inbox.Items if 
message.SenderEmailAddress.endswith('123@gmail.com')]
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class. These methods allow getting items that correspond to your conditions without iterating over all items in the folder. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: ...Thank you very much to sharing your knowledge...if you can please write down ' NewMailEx event ' code or send reference to how to do it !.VEry appriciate your answer